# Regex pattern for matching phone numbers

Tags: regex, validation

I want a regex-pattern for my phone number validator.

It has to allow *digits*, `+`, `(`, `)` and `-`.

The restrictions are:

- The `+` needs to be at the beginning of the output (something like: "+31(427)-103819" needs to be valid)
- The `+`, `(`, `)` and `-` are not required
- The output has to end with a digit
- No restrictions on length is required

Hope somebody can make me a regex for this, I have looked at different generators and ended up with something like this:

```
/^(\\+)*(\\d+)(\\()*(\\d+)(\\))*(-)*(\\d+)$/
```

This does not do what I want. Some example numbers that have to be valid:

- 190138190
- 103-10381-390101
- (0358)-103810381
- (1038)1038103
- +1081(1081)-193810
- +1903(3913)193810

Comment: Which RegEx language are you using? For example Vim regular expressions are different from Perl's..

Comment: http://regexr.com?353qd

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something very easy like this?

```
/^\+?[0-9-()]+$/
```

Comment: Think this one is the easiest. And it covered all my possibilities. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just pasted examples in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, then searched existing ones in `Community` (just double tap each item in the list until it fits for all examples).
Found this one:

```
^([().-\s0-9+]{2,}(?:(?::|x)[\s]*(?=(?:\d{1,4}))\d{1,4}[\s]*)?)$
```

Link: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?353qd

I recommend you to use such tools when you wish to find a regex for suchpresumably popular patterns as a phone number or email address.